# How to exclude environment.ts from minification & uglification

Tags: angular, webpack

We use webpack to create angular distributions. I always hoped to have **environment.js** kind of file in my deploy directory (dist). But, webpack minimize and uglify all of the things, including **environment.ts**.

I know we can create separate files **environment.prodA.ts**, **environment.prodB.ts** but I don't want to compile for each environment with **ng build --prodN** I just want to build it for **--prod** and change **environment.js** for each site.

Another workaround can be using separate file/service to get these optional settings. But, my question here to figure out if there is a way to exclude minification & uglification of environment.ts for webpack.

So that I can easily modify **todaysPortNumber** manually without building all the things.

An angular class

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
export class DoThisUpToEnvironment(){
      port: string = environment.todaysPortNumber;
}
```

environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production : true,
  todaysPortNumber : 8080
};
```

Comment: not sure why you want to exclude environment.ts since you have reference to some contents there?

Comment: @ABOS because I would like to edit some settings easily. I don't want to compile whole app for any change.

Comment: How did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @Otman Fayed I will post solution as answer here

Comment: @OthmanFayed sorry it looks I forgot to answer this question here. Some of my colleagues asked for the same, I posted something on medium https://medium.com/@davutgrbz/is-it-a-good-deployment-practice-to-rely-on-env-files-for-angular2-810b89e6a501

Comment: @DavutGürbüz thank you got the update